# Importing GPS coordinates to extract multiple DN values in ERDAS

Tags: raster, remote-sensing, erdas-imagine

I have a set of GPS points (stored as a csv for now) and would like to import these points to ERDAS to find the DN values associated with each location.

I am able to import a SHP to ERDAS but the only way I have found of extracting the DN values is via the use of the Inquire tool.

This enables me to input the lat/lon values manually to find out the DN values but I was wondering whether I am missing a more efficient batch method for doing this using a txt / csv upload?!

**Update: managed to solve this in QGIS using http://www.digital-geography.com/qgis-plugins-point-sampling-tool/**

Comment: Go ahead @Laura tell us in an answer (the more detail the better) and then mark your answer as answered.